# CsvHelper In Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, csvhelper

Im currently working on a project for a company that requires me to store data and retrieve it from a CSV file. I have tried importing CsvHelper by dragging in the different .dll files as plugins but it has always generated errors. Has anyone done this before and has a fix? if not what is the best way to make a Csv Serialiser in Unity.

Comment: Maybe something here in this Github thread will help. https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/1390

Answer (score 0):

There is a script `Unity Build.bat` in the [repository](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/master/Unity%20Build.bat) with the following content:

```
rmdir /S /Q unity\Assets\CsvHelper

dotnet build src\CsvHelper\CsvHelper.csproj -c release -o ..\..\unity\Assets\CsvHelper

pause
```

Change the output to the actual Asset folder of your project. CsvHelper should work after building the CsvHelper project into your Asset folder via this bat file.